# Adding rows and columns programmatically

Tags: c#, datagridview

```
dataGridView2.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Drive";
dataGridView2.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = root.ToString();
this.dataGridView2.Rows.Add(dataGridView2.Columns[0].DataPropertyName);

dataGridView2.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Volume Name";
dataGridView2.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = volumename.ToString();
this.dataGridView2.Rows.Add(dataGridView2.Columns[1].DataPropertyName);

dataGridView2.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Size";
dataGridView2.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = size.ToString();
dataGridView2.Rows.Add(dataGridView2.Columns[2].DataPropertyName);
```

I m not able to add rows in columns[1]&[2] because it is adding in column[0] index.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6881134/1358004 Refer This Stack Answer.

This can resolve your problem..

Comment: Putting as answer, mark it correct so further readers can refer it !